# Is there a way to include formatted text to a comment?

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

Is there a way to include formatted text to a comment?

By that I mean adding formatted source code, or literal text, as well as new lines, that is, starting new paragraphs on new lines.

Comment: The fact that the question has an answer to my question does not make my question a duplicate. My question is spefically about what formatting options are available for comments, which is not the same question as how comments work.  Even an answer to my question **has been added** to the response to that question, it doesn't make it a duplicate questions.

Comment: Nobody is trying to shame you for asking a duplicate; it's just handier for future visitors to have more signposts pointing to the same good, well-maintained answer than to have the basic information duplicated in a bunch of different places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment formatting is limited; one can *italicize*, **boldface**, or ***both***, and one can do limited `source code formatting, but no newlines`. There is a perception that more elaborate formatting is not required for comments, as comments are not supposed to be used to answer the question, and are not expected to be either elaborate or extensive; principally, they are expected to be used for requesting clarification of the question or answer to which they are attached.

Comment: To demonstrate, I've reproduced my answer as a comment: Comment formatting is limited; one can _italicize_, **boldface**, or ***both***, and one can do limited `source code formatting, but no newlines`. There is a perception that more elaborate formatting is not required for comments, as comments are not supposed to be used to answer the question, and are not expected to be either elaborate or extensive; principally, they are expected to be used for requesting clarification of the question or answer to which they are attached.

Comment: `source code` without newlines is gibberish, especially for languages that are whitespace sensitive and/or do not have line terminators.  An example is Python.

Comment: @EricTowers - In general, if you need newlines in source code, chances are that it's inappropriate for a comment in the first place. As it turns out, _any_ newlines in comments are compressed out.

Comment: My three line source code comment easily contradicts your assessment and was rendered into non-copy-pasteable gibberish.